# Submitting Concat into Salesforce with variables

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i'm creating a complex ET email -> ET Landing page -> SF task creation. 
I am currently using a `Concat` function to combine a bunch of phrases and variables into one field so I can submit this into a comment field in SF.

```
var @DescriptionBlock
SET @DescriptionBlock = Concat(@FirstName, "-", @AccountId, "This is my first selection for a date ", RequestParameter("Date1"), " ", RequestParameter("Time1"), @TimeZone, ". ", "This is my second selection for a date ", RequestParameter("Date2"), " ", RequestParameter("Time2"), @TimeZone, ". ", "This is my third selection for a date ", RequestParameter("Date3"), " ", RequestParameter("Time3"), @TimeZone, ". This is my updated phone number ", RequestParameter("Phone"), ". ")
```

My problem is that the variables `@FirstName`, `@AccountId`, `@TimeZone` are not coming through to the comment section, but the RequestParameter's are.

I've tried using the `v()` tag as well but that also didn't work.

What would cause this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You have a these options for retrieving this data in the Cloud Page:

1. Use the [**AttributeValue()**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue/) function to retrieve the personalization strings from the encoded URL coming from an email.
2. Use the [**RequestParameter()**](https://ampscript.guide/RequestParameter/) function to retrieve the value from a form POST
3. Use the [**QueryParameter()**](https://ampscript.guide/QueryParameter/) function to retrieve the value from the URL.

---

```
%%[

  var @p1, @p2, @p3
  set @p1 = AttributeValue("PersonalizationStringName")
  set @p2 = RequestParameter("FormPostVariableName")
  set @p3 = QueryParameter("URLParameterName")

]%%
@p1: %%=v(@p1)=%%
<br>@p2: %%=v(@p2)=%%
<br>@p3: %%=v(@p3)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can show how you are setting the variables, that might provide a better clue as to your problems.

Without that, here is one thought that has gotten me in the past. If your email or landing pages are calling code from or within content areas, make sure you VAR your @variables as well as SET-ting them. The VAR command, which can often be left off in simpler emails, gives you a universal scope.

Something that also bites me occasionally because I write in other languages as well, is actually leaving off the SET command when assigning a variable and I usually have to look at it three or four times before I notice that little bit of wetware error.