# Send data from de in email to landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page, einstein-recommendations

Test send failed to send. Need more help regarding this error? Open a support case through the Help & Training Portal
HTML Version

> There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.
>   Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail.
>   Script Expression: %%Email%%
>   MemberID: ##
>   JobID: 0
>
> An unrecognized expression appears in a script block.
>    Script Expression: %%Email%%
>    MemberID: ##
>    JobID: 0
>    
> Invalid Content: 
> Set @email =%%Email%%
>   There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.
>    Error 2: Script SET Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail.
>    Script Expression: %%Business
>    MemberID: ##
>    JobID: 0
>
> An unrecognized expression appears in a script block.
>    Script Expression: %%Business
>    MemberID: ##
>    JobID: 0
>    
> Invalid Content: 
> Set @AccountResponsible =%%Business
>   There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.
>    Error 3: Script SET Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail.
>    Script Expression: Concat('https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/##?'email=',@email,'&AccountResponsible=',@AccountResponsible) 
>    MemberID: ##
>    JobID: 0
>
> Invalid characters appear at the end of the parameter value
>    Function Call: Concat('https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/##?'email=',@email,'&AccountResponsible=',@AccountResponsible)
>    Parameter Value: https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/##?
>    Invalid Character: e
>    
> Invalid Content: 
> SET @landingpage =Concat('https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/##?'email=',@email,'&AccountResponsible=',@AccountResponsible)

I want to send personalized data from email to landing page the email is for test and as is follows:

```
 %%[VAR @email,@AccountResponsible,@landingpage
Set @email =%%Email%%
Set @AccountResponsible =%%Business area%%
SET @landingpage =Concat('https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/##?'email=',@email,'&AccountResponsible=',@AccountResponsible)
]%% 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href ="%%=RedirectTo(@landingpage)=%%">Click Here</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error in send is the above one.  Is there anything I am doing wrong? Help needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mixing inline AMPscript notation in an AMPscript block.  That won't work.

But, you don't need the AMPScript block in your email at all since the [**CloudPagesURL()**](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/) function will handle everything.  It encrypts and passes along the send context (the profile attributes, sending data extensions column values, etc., for the subscriber) to the Cloud Page.

Just update the CloudPagesURL() parameter below to the ID of the of our Cloud Page. That ID can be found the page's properties.

**Email:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href ="%%=CloudPagesURL(REPLACEWITHYOURCLOUDPAGESID)=%%">Click Here</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CloudPage**

```
%%[

  var @email, @AccountResponsible
  set @email = AttributeValue("Email")
  set @AccountResponsible = AttributeValue("Business Area")

]%%
<br>email: %%=v(@email)=%%
<br>AccountResponsible: %%=v(@AccountResponsible)=%%
```

[**Here's a summary**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/79409/5202) of the ways to retrieve context data on a Cloud Page:

**Reference**

- [**AttributeValue**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue)

Comment: But ,in this situationn how does the lannding page knnow from which de to take data as there is no mention of data extennsion in either of the page.Thank you

Comment: If the link is from an SFMC email, then the CloudPagesURL function passes the send context (data extension column values or profile attributes) to the page.